# Reflection in unit test

Tags: java, junit

This method is getting one value from person object and converting that value to a new value and returning it.

```
public String function(Person person)
{
   List<Activities> activities= person.getListOfActivities();
   String value1= "";
   for (Activities ac: activities) 
     {
            Bungee1 bun1= (Bungee1) ac;
            value1= bun1.getValue();
      }
    String convertedValue = "";
    if (!value1.isEmpty()) 
       {
     convertedValue= convert(value1);
       } 
  return convertedValue;
  }
```

This test case is checking for the assertEquals(expectedValue, actualValue)

```
@Test
public void testFunction()
 {
     Person person = setHardCodedValuestoPersonObject();

     Method method  =ABC.class.getDeclaredMethod("funtion", Person.class);
     method.setAccessible(true);
     String actualValue= (String)method.invoke(new ABC(), person);

      assertEquals(expectedValue,actualValue);  
  }
```

This method is in test class only and used to set the hardcode values to the object

```
 public void setHardCodedValuestoPersonObject()
  {
     Student student= new Student();
      student.setName("Sahil");
      student.setAge(27);
      student.setPlace("California");
    Activities activities = setList();
      student.setListOfActivities(activities); 
    return student;

   }
```

This method is used to set the values to the list of object

```
  public void setList()
    { 
      Person person = new Person();
       person.setId(getId());--->123
       person.setValue1(getRandomValue());--->124
    return person;
     }
```

This is my method for which I need to write unit test. I need 
    to check for expectedValue and actualValue.

The problem is the expectedValue will get changed ,it gets incremented, if I 
    change the sequence of setters method in setList()

```
for e.g. 
person.setValue1()---> its value 123 
person.setId()--->124).
```

So how to add expectedValue in testCase so that i can get different values 
according to the sequence. I thought we hardcode 
expectedValue, but in my case expectedValue will change. How to add that?

I have one question also: Can I use invoke() of Reflection twice in unit test 
for a same method or different method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source codes you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Then explain what you want to test there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The block of code you are meaning to test must be doing a single, specific thing.

If it is doing it right then there is no need of verifying it for 100 or even 10 other values. You test ONE logical concept per test and that's why we have one assert per test. So you were correct to think

> I thought we hardcode expectedValue

So always think of better tests instead of running it against multiple values.

Though running private methods directly is not a best practice, I use `Whitebox.invokeMethod()` whenever there is such need and it can be called more than once. A PowerMockito user here.

Comment: I got it but the thing is, what if some other developer add some other setter before setValue1() in setList(). Then the value of Value1 becomes 124..and then test will fail as the expectedValue was 123]

Comment: Test cases are not meant to be changed frequently (or at all actually) because you are testing a functionality. You can't foresee every possible case right. Add: Maybe you can try multiple assert statements.

Comment: Tests are not necessarily supposed to have only one assert. In fact, they should test whatever relevant property the functionality has. E.g. verifying that some fields in the database have been updated, and also verifying the return value of the function is totally acceptable. If there is a more complex property of the function that you want to test, you can take a look at randomized property based tests such as https://jqwik.net/ or just simply use parameterized tests and call it multiple times with different values.